# sort table with null as "insignificant"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns: `col_order` (int), and `name` (text). I would like to retrieve ordered rows such that, when `col_order` is not null, it determines the order, but when its null, then `name` determines the order. I thought of an order by clause such as

```
order by coalesce( col_order, name )
```

However, this won't work because the two columns have different type. I am considering converting both into bytea, but: 1) to convert the integer is there a better method than just looping moding by 256, and stacking up individual bytes in a function, and 2) how do I convert "name" to insure some sort of sane collation order (assuming name has order ... well citext would be nice but I haven't bothered to rebuild to get that ... UTF8 for the moment).

Even if all this is possible (suggestions on details welcome) it seems like a lot of work. Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

I got an excellent answer by Gordon, but it shows I didn't phrase the question correctly. I want a sort order by `name` where `col_order` represents places where this order is overridden. This isn't a well posed problem, but here is one acceptable solution:

```
col_order| name
----------------
    null | a
       1 | foo
    null | foo1
       2 | bar
```

Ie -- here if `col_order` is null name should be inserted after name closest in alphabetical order but less that it. Otherwise, this could be gotten by:

```
order by col_order nulls last, name
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok ... to get your creative juices flowing, this seems to be going in the right direction:

```
with x as ( select *, 
    case when col_order is null then null else row_number() over (order by col_order) end as ord
  from temp )
select col_order, name, coalesce( ord, lag(ord,1) over (order by name) + .5) as ord from x;
```

It gets the order from the previous row, sorted by name, when there is no `col_order`. It isn't right in general... I guess I'd have to go back to the first row with non-null `col_order` ... it would seem that sql standard has "ignore nulls" for window functions which might do this, but isn't implemented in postgres. Any suggestions?

**EDIT 3**

The following would seem close -- but doesn't work. Perhaps window evaluation is a bit strange with recursive queries.

```
with recursive x(col_order, name, n) as ( 
  select col_order, name, case when col_order is null then null 
      else row_number() over (order by col_order) * t end from temp, tot
  union all
  select col_order, name, 
    case when row_number() over (order by name) = 1 then 0 
      else lag(n,1) over (order by name) + 1 end from x
  where x.n is null ),
tot as ( select count(*) as t from temp )
select * from x;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what that ordering really is. Why is `(2, bar)` at the end there and not before `(null, foo1)`? It sounds to me like you have a vague idea of what you want, but haven't actually defined a precise ordering.

Comment: 1) for `col_order` not null, should be in order, and 2) for `col_order` null a row should be inserted immediately after last name in `name` order that is before given row.

Answer (score 3):

Just use multiple clauses:

```
order by (case when col_order is not null then 1 else 2 end),
         col_order,
         name
```

When `col_order` is `not null`, then `1` is assigned for the first sort key. When it is `null`, then `2` is assigned. Hence, the `not-nulls` will be first.

Comment: `then 1 else 2` .. Does that mean `order by` will pick up 1 as `col_order` and 2 as `name` based on condition evaluation? I am just trying to understand.

Comment: @Rahul . . . No.  It means that when `col_order` is not null, then `1` is assigned for the first sort key.  When it is null, then `2` is assigned.  Hence, the not-nulls will be first.

Comment: This can also be accomplished by "nulls last" modifier, which is in fact the default.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the explanation. Have edited your answer to include the same explanation as in your comment. Hope that's fine +1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok .. the following seems to work -- I'll leave the question "unanswered" though pending criticism or better suggestions:

Using the last_agg aggregate from [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)):

```
with
tot as ( select count(*) as t from temp ),
x as (
    select col_order, name,  
        case when col_order is null then null 
            else (row_number() over (order by col_order)) * t end as n,
        row_number() over (order by name) - 1 as i
    from temp, tot )
select x.col_order, x.name, coalesce(x.n,last_agg(y.n order by y.i)+x.i, 0 ) as n
from x
left join x as y on y.name < x.name
group by x.col_order, x.n, x.name, x.i
order by n;
```

Comment: In particular, better performance than the n^2 implied by the self join on y.name < x.name would be nice! (Indeed -- given the window expressions & embedded order by's even n^2 would be doing well!)